# Скрипт переключателя

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, кто-то встречал javascript функцию кнопки переключателя, что стоит на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/events/coming/)?

Справа от новости: ИДУ/НЕ ИДУ.

Comment: существуют вообще скрипты такого типа в паблике?
или самому прийдется писать с таймаутом и отслеживая онклик?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В гугле такого добра пруд пруди.

Например, [iPhone style checkbox using only CSS3](http://damiannicholson.com/2011/07/25/css-experiment-iphone-like-checkbox-using-only-css3.html).